# Como receber um parâmetro data WebAPI

Tags: c#, xml, desserialização

Eu recebo um xml no meu webAPI e desserializo ele.

O que eu fiz, eu peguei o modelo exato do XML que vou receber e faço uma chamada no meu serviço localmente, só a efeito de teste. Até ai tudo bem, consigo obter os campos que eu preciso. Porém, quando eu for publicar, na documentação de quem vai me enviar, eles informam que vão passar este mesmo XML, mas dentro de um parâmetro data. Eu gostaria de saber, como preparo minha Url para entender e capturar o xml com este parâmetro. Até então, eu faço a requisição, envio via body, mas não utilizo ele.

provavelmente ele virá data= xml com o conteúdo.

```
namespace WsCliMotoristas.Controllers
{
    public class XmlController : ApiController
    {
       [HttpPost]
        public void Post(HttpRequestMessage xml)
        {
            string idumov, identificadoralternativo;
            idumov = "";
            identificadoralternativo = "";
            try
            {

                string body = xml.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var Schedules = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(body);

                foreach (var elementos in Schedules.Root.Elements())
                {
                    if (elementos.Name == "alternativeIdentifier")
                    {
                         identificadoralternativo = elementos.Value;


                    }

                    foreach (var historicos in elementos.Elements())
                    {
                        if (historicos.Name == "activityHistory")
                        {
                            idumov = historicos.FirstAttribute.Value;

                        }

                    }
                }

                GetEntrega entrega = new GetEntrega();

                entrega.GeraEntregaAsync(idumov);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amigo, pode ter o formato de xml, mas ao que tudo indica você está recebendo uma string. Não está claro o suficiente, mas pelo que pude entender, o consumidor de sua api deseja enviar um json passando essa string em um atributo chamado data.

Comment: " parâmetro data" o que necessariamente significa isso? um objeto nomeado data? é possível editar e colocar a documentação de onde você recebeu essa informação?

Comment: O body da requisição que ele faz no meu serviço virá assim: data= Conteúdo do XML

Comment: No meu teste, consumindo meu serviço, eu simplesmente mando o xml no corpo, sem parametro algum. Body = Conteudo do XML / o cliente me manda dessa forma: body data= conteudo do xml

Comment: Se eu não preparar o meu serviço para ele esperar esse parâmetro chamado data vou ter um erro. Estou finalizando ainda, por isso não publiquei e testei isso diretamente na chamada dele, mas está nítido que terei um erro.

Comment: Poste um exemplo dessa requisição que você deverá receber